# checking the end of a c string array

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

Im trying to find the end of a word for example school and at the end of a word put a s on to it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    plural[i] = orig[i];

    if (plural[i] == NULL) {
        plural[i] = 's';
        plural[i + 1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: The end of a C character array is marked by a `\0` character aka the null terminator. But I doubt that is what you need.

Comment: I get that, thats why I put the null in the if statement to check for the end of it

Comment: There's some very important that's missing from your question. That would be an actual question.

Comment: Im copying whats in the original array to the plural array and then adding an s onto the end of it

Comment: Not to mention the declaration of `plural` to insure you are not invoking *Undefined Behavior* by overrunning your array bounds.

Comment: You can use `strlen`

Comment: That is still not a question i.e a sentence that ends with "?"

Comment: we have to use 10 for the length of the array

Comment: @poppy - you may want to look backwards in the loop to insure you loop counter protects your array bounds, e.g. `for (i = 1; i + 1 < sizeof plural; i++) { if (!plural[i-1]) { plural[i-1] = 's'; plural[i] = 0; break; }` (**note:** this presumes `plural` is a validly declared `array` declared *in scope*)

Answer (score 2):

Your code may function of the string in `orig` is less than 10 characters long and `NULL` is defined as `0`.

But note that `NULL` is used to represent the null pointer, not the null byte at the end of a string.  `NULL` can be defined this way:

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

In this case, your code would generate a warning upon compilation.

It is considered good style to write `'\0'` for the null byte at the end of a string. The null character constant has the same value, `0` with type `int`, but is more explicit for the purpose of representing the null byte.

You should test if `orig[i]` is non null instead of iterating to `10`:

```
char orig[] = "world";
char plural[10];
int i;

for (i = 0; orig[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    plural[i] = orig[i];
}
plural[i] = 's';
plural[i + 1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the position of null-terminator (`'\0'`) by the following:

```
int len;
for(len = 0; cstr[len]; ++len);
```

This is a possible minimal implementation of [`strlen`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) which is stands for to determine the length of a `char` array. In example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char cstr[10] = "Test";

    size_t len;
    for(len = 0; cstr[len]; ++len);

    if(sizeof(cstr) > len + 1) {
        cstr[len++] = 's';    
        cstr[len] = '\0'; 
    }
    printf("%s\n", cstr);
}
```

**Note:** As David C. Rankin mentioned in comments, you have to protect the array bounds. Knowing that this is an array, you can read its size with the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, you're right, I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The most important part of this exercise is to insure you learn to protect your array bounds. If you declare an *array of char [10]*, then the longest *string* it can hold is `9-chars + the nul-byte`. If you plan to add a character to the end (e.g. `'s'`), then that means the original string can be no longer than `8-chars`.

If you declare `plural` as:

```
char plural[10] = "";          /* note the initialization to all `0` */
```

then the maximum number of characters that can be held in `plural` in order to use `plural` as a *string* is `sizeof plural - 1` chars (*preserving space for the *nul-byte*). So you can set a `max` for the length of your string with:

```
char plural[10] = "";          /* note the initialization to all `0` */
int max = sizeof plural - 1;
```

Then after you find your original string length, you can **validate** that there is sufficient room for the *nul-byte*, e.g.

```
if (len >= max) {   /* validate room for 's' available */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: adding 's' will exceed array size.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Putting all the pieces together in a short example, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char plural[10] = "", *def = "school";
    int len = 0,
        max = sizeof plural - 1;

    if (argc == 1) {    /* if no argument given, copy def to plural */
        char *p = def;
        for (int i = 0; *p && i < max; i++, len++)
            plural[i] = *p++;
    }
    else    /* otherwise copy argv[1] to plural */
        len = snprintf (plural, max, "%s", argv[1]);

    if (len >= max) {   /* validate room for 's' available */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: adding 's' will exceed array size.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    plural[len] = 's';  /* add 's' - (nul-terminated via initialization) */

    printf ("original : %s\nappended : %s\n", argc > 1 ? argv[1] : def, plural);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/plural
original : school
appended : schools

$ ./bin/plural 12345678
original : 12345678
appended : 12345678s

$ ./bin/plural 123456789
error: adding 's' will exceed array size.
```

**note:** if you are more comfortable with *array indexes* than with *pointer arithmetic*, you can use the following equivalent statement for the length finding and copy:

```
    if (argc == 1)      /* if no argument given, copy def to plural */
        for (int i = 0; def[i] && i < max; i++, len++)
            plural[i] = def[i];
    else    /* otherwise copy argv[1] to plural */
        len = snprintf (plural, max, "%s", argv[1]);
```

Look things over. There are many, many different ways to approach this. A normal addition would be to include `string.h` and use `strlen` and `strcpy` or `memcpy` instead of a loop to find your length or copy characters to `plural` (note: for long strings `memcpy` will be more efficient, but for 10 char -- it makes no difference) Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Minor: `nul-byte` and _nul-byte_ are OK to call `'\0'`.  The spec calls it the _null character_.  The only ref to "NUL" is a comment about ASCII.

Comment: You are an astute observer. To be honest, I usually just use *nul-byte* because I'm being lazy and wanting to avoid typing *nul-terminating character* or wanting to avoid the single-line comment tripping the horizontal scrollbar boundary `:)` -- I'll tighten the verbiage in the future.

Comment: There is small inconsistency: `len = snprintf(plural, max, "%s", argv[1]);` will not compute `len` the same way as in the default case, nor will `plural` contain the same characters if both sources were too long.  For the current use case, this has not consequences, but it might be a bit confusing.